# Word or Short Phrase to Describe Standing In Relation to One's Own Past Performance

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

I'm working on a website for encouraging habit change that includes a table consisting of the user's current streak and two of that same user's better streaks and two of his or her worse streaks, along with performance rankings, like so:

```
| 4 | Even Longer Streak  |
| 5 | Longer Streak       |
| 6 | CURRENT STREAK      |
| 7 | Shorter Streak      |
| 8 | Even Shorter Streak |
```

What would a good title for this table be? It should be short (preferably less than five words) and indicate the purpose of the table: to allow the user to view his current performance in the perspective of his past performance.

Ideas I've discarded:

- Anything with "rank" or "ranking": Implies rank within a group of people.
- "Performance": Doesn't sufficiently indicate the table's purpose.

(For anyone who is curious: [A longer discussion of the purpose of this table can be found over on UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76312/making-a-streak-visualization-more-intuitive).)

**EDIT:** Here's how it looks now:

[image: Current Design]

The fact that the numbering starts at `2` indicates there is one more longer streak that isn't shown.

Comment: Perhaps "Performance Index?" Sounds like something you'd see on an investment dashboard, not a self-improvement site. Or maybe it does fit...

Comment: "Trend" may capture what you want?

Comment: I think Bookeater's and Nathan Arthur's combined: *self-improvement trend* or *self-improvement performance index*

Comment: The idea is really to tap into some of the psychology behind ["ghost cars"](http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/c760ab5370f8493eb60fa43ae8f75d0a/200476058/ghostcar530.jpg) in racing games. Perhaps "Personal Bests" would be a good title.

Comment: How about Progress, Progression, Achievement, Attainment?

Comment: Achievement seems good, or "Relative Achievement".

Comment: Personal Performance Statistics

Comment: Do you plan to put those words ("even longer streak", etc) literally in that table, or will it say, for example, "21 days, 15 days, 8 days, 3 days, 2 days"?  Or both?

Comment: Will it show the _longest_ and _shortest_ streaks, if more than five streaks have been recorded?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock It only shows two longer and two shorter, not longest and shortest. [This is how it looks now.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SwFl1.png)

Answer (score 7):

*[Consistency](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/consistency)*

> 1.1 The quality of achieving a level of performance which does not vary greatly in quality over time:

*The purpose of tracking streaks is to encourage **consistency** of performance.*

Answer (score 0):

**Health-Related Behavioural Change Index**

or

**Trends in Duration of Smoking Abstinence** (based on additional information supplied by OP)

or

**Overcoming Habitual Behaviours**